# Extending access token

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to exchange my short lived access token for a long lived one. Here is my code

```
    var params = {};
    params['client_id'] = 'XXXXXX';//REMOVED APP ID
    params['client_secret'] ='XXXXXX';//REMOVED APP SECRET
    params['grant_type'] = 'fb_exchange_token';
    params['fb_exchange_token'] = 'XXXXXX';//accessToken
    params['response_type'] = 'text';

    FB.api('/oauth/access_token', params,  dojo.hitch(this,function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }));
```

In fire bug when i see the response, i get the new access token and its expiry time. However the reaponse variable in the code above has an error object instead of the access token and the expiry time.

Has anyone face this before? Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And the error object contains _what_? Anyway, this is not supposed to be done client-side at all – since it needs the app secret, and you do __not__ want to expose that in any client-side code, where everyone could easily find it …

Comment: hey CBroe, the error object is as below
{"error":{"type":"http","message":"unknown error"}}
What would be the best way for me to exhange the access token at hand for a long lived access token

Comment: Server-side, as described in the docs.